# Matlab GLIBCXX, CXXABI error

Tags: matlab

I am trying to run a code in Matlab and it keeps throwing me these errors

```
> /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version
> `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/bin/inkscape)
> /usr/bin/inkscape:
> /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version
> `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/bin/inkscape)
> /usr/bin/inkscape:
> /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version
> `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/bin/inkscape)
```

Although these GLIBCXX and CXXABI are already installed. 
P.S: I don't have much knowledge about these system libraries and stuff, so I apologize in advance if my question seems silly

Comment: What are you trying to run?

Comment: @Suever: I am trying to run  [this script](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/52700-plot2latex) to convert my figure to tex file